# Why 1.2 == true returns false if Boolean(1.2) is actually true?

Tags: javascript, boolean, type-conversion, equals-operator

Brushing up on `==` and `===`, I can't really convince myself with an explanation about this.

I take a floating point number and do a `==` with a `Boolean` `true`. It returns `false`. But when I explicitely convert the floating point number to a Boolean, it returns true. Shouldn't the == actually first convert the 1.2 to a Boolean and than compare it to the true on the other side?

```
> Boolean(1.2)
true
> 1.2 == true
false
```

On the other hand, an "integer" will behave as I expect it.

```
> 1 == true
true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated above `1.2` will not be converted into boolean first.

According the the [abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), the following steps will be performed

- `1.2 == true`
- `1.2 == toNumber(true)` (In algorithm, step no 7)
- `1.2 == 1` (In algorithm, step no 1)
- `false`

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't actually the number on the left be converted to Boolean and not the Boolean on the right to a number? I haven't yet devoted time to read the ECMA standard, so sorry for asking.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster No, When you use `==` operator to compare values, Based on AECAlgorithm both of its type will be coerced to the type `number`. I had given the step numbers of the original algorithm, have a look at those. It will give you a firm grip on this concept.

Comment: OK, I was watching a video course, where the narrator comments on this and he explains that the number gets converted, not the Boolean. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Barmar Troll alert, actually it's this course: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/javascript-best-practices I don't think asking questions, especially when in doubt, is bad.

Comment: I was just making a little joke, sorry for bothering you. Could you tell me which video it was in, I'm not going to wade through 2 hours looking for it.